# Android: Unit Testing Media Playback

Tags: android, unit-testing, audio

I'm working on applications which have audio and video playback as core elements of the user experience.  Something I'm noticing is that across the wide array of android devices on the market playback will or won't work in various ways.  The system will often behave as though playback completed successfully (calling callbacks, not erroring) even though the user only heard a portion of the audio, or certain parts didn't play correctly.

I've got a good emulation environment set up for running Unit Tests on various devices, however I don't have any good methods to verify the actual output/input to the system during these.

Are there any techniques for how to unit test and verify that Audio or Video is actually played (i.e. produced audible sound?) on these devices?